# Insert the foreign key from Option Select in PHP Web Form

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a web form used to add data to a db from PHP.

Lets say my Database is organised into 2 Tables called Appointments and the other called Clubs. Clubs contains clubid and name.

My web form is designed for adding appointments.

I have a field in the form where I can type in the clubid, type in a number and add the event via simple option select in html: 
        Name of the Club:

How do I make this an option select, echoing the clubid?
And if possible, displaying the Club Name but inserting the clubid into Appointments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short snippet of code:

```
 <?php
    //your connection to the db and query would go here
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
     {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
     }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM clubs";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
?>


      Select Club: 
        <select id="club" name="club">
          <option value = ""></option>
        <?php
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<option value='.$row['id'].'>'.$row['field'].'</option>';
          }
        ?> 
        </select>
```

The select list gets populated with the clubid #, then it can be posted to another php script or ajax.

Comment: Perfect, just had to adjust to my existing statements and such. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

it's much more easier if you just use the select option. load the select box using clubs table and assign the clubid to option value as below

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['clubid']?>"><?php echo $row['name']?></option>
```

then use that select name to get value for the clubid

```
$clubid = $_POST['selectboxname'];
```

insert the $clubid to table.